# Using "statfs" on Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, hardware, hard-drive

I need to retrieve information about a hard disk and am using the statfs function to do so.

- When your computer displays free space on the HD, does it use "free blocks" or "free blocks available to unpriveleged user"?
- Does statfs work with SSDs?
- How would the "path" to the main hard drive be stored? On windows it's generally C:, but I am new to OSX.

The man pages don't seem to provide a very comprehensive look of how statfs works.

Mac OSX Snowleopard using C/Objective-C. Xcode 3.2.6

Comment: do you mind showing some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Look at `man statfs`; the structure returned has both counts available (`f_bfree` and `f_bavail`).¹

2) Yes, it works on filesystems, not hard drives, so it doesn't matter what type of hard drive (if any) the filesystem is on.

3) `/`

¹ In case the first part of the question was not about what `statfs` returns but what “the computer” displays in general, I guess the answer depends on the program used to display the amount of free space. Compare the two values returned by `statfs` to those displayed by the program you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks  that answers everything except for Q1. Does the computer itself use f_bfree or f_bavail? For example if I access my harddrive through finder, it displays the amount of free space. Is that free space f_bfree or f_bavail?